# Java ValidationAPI library that supports DTD

Tags: java, validation, dtd

I was using multiple xsd schemas to validate XML documents. This was a piece of code that I was using to do that:

```
public static Schema createSchemaXSD(InputStream inputXSD, LSResourceResolver resolver) throws SAXException {
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    factory.setResourceResolver(resolver);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(inputXSD);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    return schema;
}
```

`LSResourceResolver` is interface for developing a class that can resolve loading of xsd schemas that root schema includes in its xsd. I wrote an implementation that loads included files from classpath, since my schemas are packed there (not on a filesystem)

Suddenly, I needed to switch to validate against multiple DTDs, so I changed code to:

```
public static Validator createValidatorDTD(InputStream inputDTD, LSResourceResolver resolver) throws SAXException {
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.XML_DTD_NS_URI);
    factory.setResourceResolver(resolver);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(inputDTD);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    return validator;
}
```

Unfortunately this don't work. It throws an exception on creating a factory for SchemaFactory:

```
No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml could be loaded
```

I did a research based on articles: [Java XML Validation API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html) and [java.xml.validation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html). They both specify that `XMLConstants.XML_DTD_NS_URI` is supported, but not implemented in Sun's JDK 5 (and in JDK 6 as far as I can see) and that I should use some other library that supports DTD validation.

I tried to search on Google, but didn't find anything (or I didn't know how to search). I know that you can validate document against DTD using DOM and TrAX, but these require that you have DTDs on your filesystem. My DTDs and schemas are on the classpath and so I need custom loading for my DTDs. That is why I used `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` and `javax.xml.validation.Schema` in the first place as they offer much bigger flexibility.

So my question is: Is there a library (or libraries) that supports DTD validation through java validation API (`XML_DTD_NS_URI`), that I can use. I am open for different type of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to concatenate your DTD and XML and parse or validate with no .schema. An example:

```
String dtd;
String xml;
....
....

src = new InputSource( new ByteArrayInputStream( (dtd + xml).getBytes()) );
try {
    factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);
    factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    partnersDoc = builder.parse(src);
} catch ( ParserConfigurationException ex ){
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```